# Getting raw text files from a Solr snapshot?

Tags: database, solr, machine-learning, text-files

I have a Solr database snapshot. The database is an archive of published blog posts (plus a bunch of metadata for each post). The snapshot is tens of thousands of posts.

I want to run some machine learning algorithms and topic modeling on the posts. So I don't need the database per se, I just want to get the raw text of the posts and the metadata in some simple form. Can anyone tell me how to open or extract that info without actually installing Solr?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the Solr Index when you mean the Solr database snapshot.
Solr index is basically a lucene index and you can use the [Lucene apis](http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs144/projects/lucene/) to just read the index and extract data from the fields.
This would not need Solr to be installed.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll have a look at Lucene.